# Get id of collection in foreach

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the ID of the share, but, I'm do a foreach in links, look:

```
@foreach($user->getRelation('shares')->pluck('links') as $link)

{{ $link->first()->title }} //works

{{ //get the ID, of the current share }}

@endforeach
```

How can I do it?

dd($user->shares);

```
Collection {#338 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Share {#343 ▼
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 7
        "link_id" => 3
        "user_id" => 1
        "shared_in" => null
        "content" => "testetste"
        "created_at" => "2018-02-02 15:46:13"
      ]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "links" => Collection {#349 ▶}
      ]
    }
    1 => Share {#344 ▶}
    2 => Share {#345 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `id` as the second parameter for `pluck()` method:

```
@foreach($user->getRelation('shares')->pluck('links', 'id') as $id => $link)
    {{ $link->first()->title }}
    {{ $id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Alexey eye catching! ... coulding pass by without voting up .... (`as $id => $link`)

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, your shares? are already shared with the view in their entirety and so plucking the links and ids doesn't really save you much performance meaning this loop is unnecessarily complicated.

```
@foreach($user->getRelation('shares') as $share)
    {{ $share->links->first()->title }}
    {{ $share->id }}
@endforeach
```

If however, all you want to use in this view instance is the link and id, then I would recommend modifying your query in the controller to reduce the size of the overall collection being sent to your view instance.